# HW in kodi with atom N270 is possible?

Tags: kodi, atom

HW acceleration in kodi 18.6  with atom N270 is possible running ubuntu-16.04. ?

```
$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0 
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0 
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i915_drv_video.so 
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1 vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

Comment: What is the output if `vainfo` for now? (install it from `vainfo` package if not installed)

Comment: libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i915_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit

Comment: No, not possible, no matter what you install. Atom N270 was very basic back in 2009, and is completely inadequate today.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install single package with

```
sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver
```